# value specific query, how to substiture "No Errors found" instead of "no data"

Tags: promql

using this query,
(((status != 1) != 2) != 3)
how can i replace "no data" (all samples have status ==1 for example) with "No Errors found"?

im using OpsRamp, not grafana, trying to produce a list of hostnames with the specific status code returned for each host with status == 0 or == 4. sometimes, all have status >= 1 <= 3 which results in "no data" or "no series", confusing for a user.

tried absent and absent_over_time

Comment: Prometheus doesn't return 'No data', it returns an empty array. How it handled is fully depends on your client, and should be configured there.